# TCP server written in Java client written in C receive error (encoding)

Tags: java, c, tcp

I have a TCP server that is written in Java, and a client that is written in C.

I am sending array of chars from the client, but the only thing that is received in the server is a blank line, there aren’t any characters.

Do you know why is this happening and how can I solve this problem? How can I encode the message in the server part?

Maybe the problem is in decoding? I know that in C programming language `char` is `byte`, and I know in Java it is 2 bytes.

The part of the server that is written in Java is :

```
public class main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    TCPServerHandler handler; // Креирање на handler за TCP серверот
    handler = new TCPServerHandler() {

        //Доколку сакате да го опширите onConnect
        @Override
        public boolean onConnect(INonBlockingConnection inbc) throws IOException, BufferUnderflowException, MaxReadSizeExceededException {
            super.onConnect(inbc); //Задолжително повикување на super.onConnect(inbc)
            //Доколку сакате да го дополните onConnect
            System.out.println("Connected:"+inbc.getRemoteAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+inbc.getRemotePort());
            return true;
        }

        //Доколку сакате да го опширите onDisconnect
        @Override
        public boolean onDisconnect(INonBlockingConnection inbc) throws IOException {
            super.onDisconnect(inbc); //Задолжително повикување на super.onDisconnect(inbc)
            //Доколку сакате да го дополните onDisconnect
            System.out.println("Discconected:"+inbc.getRemoteAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+inbc.getRemotePort());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onData(INonBlockingConnection inbc) throws IOException, BufferUnderflowException, ClosedChannelException, MaxReadSizeExceededException {

             String data = this.readString(inbc);
             int sizeofdata = data.length();
             System.out.println(sizeofdata);
            //Што понатака зависи од самата апликација
            System.out.println(data);
          //  this.writeString(inbc, "OK");
            return true;
        }
    };
    TCPServer server = new TCPServer(9912, handler); // Иницијализирање на серверот на порта 9001 со handler
    server.start(); //Започнување на серверот
    try {
        while (true) {
            if (server.getServerStatus() == true) { //Проверка дали започнал
                System.out.println("Server started");
                break;
            }
        }

        while (true) {
            //Што и да ќе правте откако ќе започне серверот
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So, here I am reading like string, and maybe that is the problem.
The client part written in c is:

```
static unsigned int barcode[17];

void PRINT_BARCODE_ONLY(void)
{
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    barcode[i] = rx_buffer[6 + i] - 0x30;
  }
  barcode[16] = 35;
  printf("%c[1;31mBARCODE: ", 27);
  for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
  {
    printf("%X", barcode[i]);
  }
}

int SEND_BARCODE_TCP(void)
{
  int sock_descriptor;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;

  struct hostent *server;
  sock_descriptor = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

  if (sock_descriptor < 0)
    printf("Failed creating socket\n");

  bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

  //server = gethostbyname("10.10.1.120");
  server = gethostbyname("192.168.123.103");
  //server = gethostbyname("127.0.0.1");

  if (server == NULL)
  {
    printf("Failed finding server name\n");
    return -1;
  }

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  memcpy((char *) &(serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr), (char *) (server->h_addr),
      server->h_length);

  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(9912);
  //serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);

  if (connect(sock_descriptor, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,
      sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
  {
    printf("Failed to connect to server\n");
    return -1;
  }

  else
    printf("Connected successfully \n");

  int count = write(sock_descriptor, barcode, sizeof(barcode));

  if (count < 0)
    printf("Failed writing rquested bytes to server\n");

  close(sock_descriptor);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: STOP SHOUTING IN YOUR TITLE, PLEASE.

Comment: I am very sorry it was not on purpose.
It won't happen again.
thanks for the help

Comment: It's acceptable in terms of purpose, just the title's capitalization conveyed shouting at us.

Comment: You seem to be sending 17 `unsigned int`s. Would mind showing us how `barcode` is initialised/set?

Comment: Also you should check wether `write()` really wrote the amount of data you passed in as 3rd parameter. `write()` is specified to possibly also return after having written less. So check its return value, count and loop around `write()` as long as needed.

Answer (score 0):

TCP socket streams are byte based.  This is why an encoding is used to convert chars to bytes when you read/write.  It appears the main method `readString()` is missing, but I assume you have specified the enocding the C program is using or assumed the default encoding is ok.